# Audacious 3.9 stops playback after each track? (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, audacious

Been away fro two weeks, turn on my main work machine, load up a playlist in audacious and playback stops after each track played. Tried it on random too, can't see any reason why in the UI. Never had this happen before in years of happy listening with audacious from 16.04 onwards!

Anyone got a fix? it's killing me!

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at  "play" in the menu, and look if "no playlist advanced " is on.   (or Crtl + N)

Comment: Awesome, thanks that was it. Must have been in focus when I created a new document somewhere! Thanks.